# How do I write a Func<T, bool> to return the entity with the most children?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, c#-4.0, repository-pattern

I have a repository accessing my Entity Framework.  I have a method that looks like this:

```
public TEntity FindOne(Expression<Func<TEntity, bool>> criteria)
{
   var query = _queryAll.Where(criteria);
   return query.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I have 2 Entities that have a one to many relation.  Lets call them `Courses` and `Students`.  A `Course` can have multiple `Students`.  I'd like to write a query that returns the Course that has the most students.

```
Courses.OrderByDescending(x=>x.Students.Count()).FirstOrDefault();
```

But how would I write that as a `Func<T, bool>` ?

I hope it's not

```
(x=>x.OrderBy(y=>y.Students.Count()).FirstOrDefault().id == x.id)
```

Because adding another criteria looks like it wouldn't work:

```
    (x=>x.OrderBy(y=>y.Students.Count())
      .FirstOrDefault().id == x.id 
        && x.CourseName == "CS101")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not at all clear why you'd put the `&& x.Course == "CS101"` at the end. What is that even meant to mean? I strongly suspect the problem is in your design of trying to cram everything into a single `Where` clause in your `FindOne` method. Quite simply, not everything can easily be expressed that way.

Also, you should be using `OrderByDescending` so that the first result has the *most* students.

Other than that, using ordering seems fairly reasonable to me, in terms of the overall query - but it won't fit neatly into your `FindOne` scheme.

EDIT: This is a bigger problem than just requiring two conditions. You *could* write:

```
x => x.CourseId == "CS101" && 
     x.Students.Count() == Courses.Where(x => x.CourseId == "CS101"))
                                  .Max(x => x.Students.Count())
```

... but the problem is that at that point you've got to have access to `Courses` anyway, which I'd imagine you're trying to get away from. Aside from that, it should *work* but it's grotesque.

If you *can* get access to courses, you might as well ignore `FindOne` and write the query yourself:

```
var course = courses.Where(course => course.CourseId == "CS101")
                    .OrderByDescending(course => course.Students.Count())
                    .FirstOrDefault();
```

That's clearly simpler than the first version.

Comment: thanks for the orderby bug - fixed.  I guess what I'm unsure of is how to add a second criteria.  I think my property name "Course" was confusing and I didn't read it - also fixed.

Comment: Thanks.. I came here because it was looking grotesque :)  I think this is more a failing with my repository (which doesn't expose IQueryable) than anything.  Possibly I could add a FindTopOne(Expression<Func<T,bool>> criteria, Expression<Func<T,TKey>> sort)